# How to use dual real camera to do stereoscopic tracking?

Tags: android, stereo-3d

I have two real camera on Samsung tablet.
I want to know where can I find example about how to use them to do stereoscopic tracking?

Many thanks.

YL

Comment: Can you get separate pictures from them?

Comment: Not yet. I am looking for an example to do this.

Comment: Strange that you did not ask for that.